# Drill down in DC.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am building a dashboard that needs a drill-down pie chart. Does DC.js support drilling down natively? I have implemented drill down in Highcharts quite easily in the past, but we need support for cross filtering and dimensions, so I would like to be able to use DC.js.

Thanks.

Comment: nope, i think you'd implement this either by changing the data when a category is clicked, or you could use a [sunburst chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/907), which has similar functionality but is not yet a part of the dc.js core.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. You really should be looking to use crossfilter.js and dc.js together. You will find this a lot quicker than implementing drill down in another charting library if you have more than just the one chart. If you’ve just the one chart, than it would make sense to use one of the many javascript charting libraries. I recommend [AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) as it is easy to write custom listeners with their api.

Comment: Ryan, do you  have any examples of AMCharts with crossfilter?